# How do I define a "or" function in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell

How do I define an "or" function in Haskell, in which I only can use && and not?
My task is to write a function thereof. However, I do not know how to do that.
Can you help me?

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like homework and it's not Haskell related in the least. What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Have you looked up [de Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)?

Comment: maybe we should implement a DSL where you can only **and** and **or** and then use this ;) ... btw: you are learning Java and Haskell at the same time as a total beginner? *Wow*

Answer (score 2):

Use [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to convert between `or` and `and`.